# IN operator support in YugabyteDB YSQL

Tags: yugabytedb

[Question posted by a user on [YugabyteDB Community Slack](https://www.yugabyte.com/slack)]

We are using YSQL on YugabyteDB 2.8.3.
Does yugabyte support the `IN` operator using YSQL syntax?

Something like…`DELETE FROM Customers WHERE Country IN ('Germany', 'France', 'UK');`

The `Country` column is an array in our case.

The yugabyte documentation says,

IN should be applied on records but not array

The combination = ANY is functionally equivalent to IN (but IN is illegal syntax when the RHS is an array).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alternatively use the `<@` [array containment operator](https://docs.yugabyte.com/preview/api/ysql/datatypes/type_array/functions-operators/comparison/#the-160-160-160-160-and-160-160-160-160-operators-1):

Try this:

```
select array['germany']::text[] <@ 
       array['germany', 'france', 'uk']::text[];
```

Or (if you insist on doing without the self-documenting typecasts):

```
select array['germany'] <@
       array['germany', 'france', 'uk'];
```

Or, if you prefer to use array literals rather then the array constructor, this:

```
select '{germany}'::text[] <@
       '{germany,france,uk}'::text[];
```

The `text[]` typecasts are necessary here.

B.t.w., I recommend to anybody who's working with arrays in YugabyteDB (or in vanilla PG) that they read the entire YSQL doc on the topic. This section contains the subsection whose URL I gave.

*Regards, bryn@yugabyte.com*

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this works:

```
create table Customers as
select * from unnest(array['Germany', 'France', 'UK','Switzerland']) Customers(Country);

DELETE FROM Customers WHERE Country IN ('Germany', 'France', 'UK');
```

The `IN` operates on a set. But you can transform an array to a set with `UNNEST` if you need to:

```
WHERE Country IN (select unnest(array['Germany', 'France', 'UK']));
```